# Is it posible to override existing property's type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm using [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage) with failback language, so `resolvedLanguage` to me is certain like `'zh'|'en'`, is it possible to override `resolvedLanguage`'s type (originally type as string)? so that when i use this value i don't have to use `as 'zh'|'en'` to convert it's type.

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible example. Please keep in mind, that you are able to extend existing interface with another one through declaration merging. However it works only for interfaces

Comment: @captain-yossarian I expand some detail to my question, you can check  i18next's type definetion for the existing type.

Comment: Extending this interface with declaration merging will ultimately do nothing, because `string` extended by `'zh' | 'en'` is still `string`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overriding module type is a little trickier than extending its interface, because we cannot use declaration merging. Still we can do a little workaround instead.

i18next.d.ts:

```
declare module 'i18next' {
  import { i18n } from 'i18next/index'; // Original interface is imported from i18next/index to avoid circular imports.
  type I18nWithLanguages = i18n & {
    resolvedLanguage: 'zh' | 'en';
  };
  const i18WithLanguages: I18nWithLanguages;
  export default i18WithLanguages;
};
```

We just import original `i18n` interface, modify to our needs and export it again.

Effect:

```
// Error: Type '"pl"' is not assignable to type '"zh" | "en"'
i18n.resolvedLanguage = 'pl';
```