# How to make TypeScript not emit `/// <reference path="…" />` directives for ambient declaration files?

Tags: typescript, tsc, type-declaration

### Background

I'm writing a package using [Lit](https://lit.dev). To prevent accidental interpolation of nonsense values in templates, I have created `src/lit.d.ts` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771467):

```js
declare module "lit" {
  import { html as htmlFromLit } from "lit/index";

  export * from "lit/index";

  export const html: (strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: Array<string | number /* etc */>) => ReturnType<typeof htmlFromLit>;
}
```

This way, I can write my code as usual and still get more type safety than Lit itself provides:

```js
import { html } from "lit"; // ← standard, idiomatic import

export const h = html`<p>${null}</p>`;
//                         ~~~~ Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
```

### Problem

Consumers of my package get this compilation error:

```
node_modules/my-package/dist/index.d.ts:1:22 - error TS6053: File '/…/consuming-project/node_modules/my-package/src/lit.d.ts' not found.

1 /// <reference path="../src/lit.d.ts" />
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Content of `/…/consuming-project/node_modules/my-package/dist/index.d.ts`:

```js
/// <reference path="../src/lit.d.ts" />
export declare const h: import("lit-html").TemplateResult<1>;
```

My observations/notes:

- `lit.d.ts` is indeed not among the emitted files in `dist/`, but even if it were, the reference would not point to it, because the `src` directory isn't included in the published npm package.
- There are no `reference` directives in the *source* code of my package; TypeScript injects them whenever it compiles a module that imports `"lit"`.
- Even if I could make TypeScript include `lit.d.ts` among the emitted files, I don't think I want to, because its purpose is only to aid the *development* of `my-package`.
- If I manually remove the triple-slash directives in the emitted files before running `npm pack`, the consuming project compiles just fine.
- The problem is still present in TypeScript 4.9.5 and 5.0.4.

**How can I make TypeScript not emit these directives, or otherwise solve this problem?**

### Project details (for reference)

#### File tree

```
.
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── lit.d.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

#### `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc -p ."
  },
  "files": [ "dist/**/*" ],
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lit": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

#### `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2019",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
  ],
}
```